# Nondiscrete measure on the power set of an uncountable set

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Th following is exercise 1.4.25 from Terry Tao's Measure Theory:

> Exercise 25 Let ${X}$ be an at most countable set with the discrete ${\sigma}$-algebra. Show that every measure ${\mu}$ on this measurable space can be uniquely represented in the form $\mu = \sum_{x \in X} c_x \delta_x$ for some ${c_x \in [0,+\infty]}$, thus $ \mu(E) = \sum_{x \in E} c_x$ for all ${E \subset X}$. (This claim fails in the uncountable case, although showing this is slightly tricky.)

The last sentence intrigues me. I have done some search and found that under the continuum hypothesis, there is no non-discrete probability measure on the set of power sets. On the other hand, if we assume measurable cardinal exists, then there exists one. However, I don't think this is what the author intended, and the answer is possibly much simpler if we don't require $\mu$ to be a probability measure. Anyone knows a simple example of a nondiscrete measure on the power set of an uncountable set? (If $X$ is uncountable, the sum is interpreted to be the sup over all finite sums)

Comment: I think that this comment might be more about the fact that in general there may not exists $c_x$ such that $\mu=\sum_{x\in X} c_x\delta_x$. It is not clear from that text under what condition this fails, but for sure it does if $\mu$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and we take the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Also note that you have to extend the definition of sum to any set, which is doable in some way (but converges if only countably many $c_x$ are non zero for every fixed set we want to measure)

Comment: Yeah the uncountable sum of nonnegative numbers $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$ is defined to be the sup over all finite sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment in the last sentence in  exercise 1.4.25 from Terry Tao's Measure Theory is about measures, not probabilities.

The OP asks: "Anyone knows a simple example of a nondiscrete measure on the power set of an uncountable set?"

Here is a simple example. Let $X$ be any uncountable set and let $2^X$ be the power set of $X$. For every $E \in 2^X$, define $\mu(E) = 0$, if $E$ is countable and $\mu(E)=+\infty$, if $E$ is uncountable.

It is easy to prove that $\mu$ is a measure defined on $2^X$. It is also easy to see that for any singleton $\{a\} \in 2^X$, $\mu(\{a\})=0$. So, $\mu$ is a non-discrete measure ($\mu$ can **not** be represented in the form $\mu = \sum_{x \in X} c_x \delta_x$ for some ${c_x \in [0,+\infty]}$).

Comment: Feels like this doesn't qualify as "tricky"

Comment: @Bananach ,  "tricky" is a rather subjective concept.

Comment: That's why I said "feels". Anyway, personally i don't think that's what Tao meant, but I don't have a better guess either.

Comment: @Bananach  , Note that Tao writes  "slightly tricky". I believe he may have meant the kind of example I presented. Anyway, the question is not to about what Tao exactly thought, the question is to present "a simple example of a nondiscrete measure on the power set of an uncountable set".

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct and it presents a simple example of a non-discrete measure defined on the powerset of an uncountable set, as asked in the OP.

Comment: Fair point, I missed the actual question beyond the quote. I'll remove my downvote when I can. Edit: SE unfortunately won't let me do that until the answer is changed.

Comment: @Bananach , I have edited the answer now. You can remove the downvote now. I'll appreciate that.